# Add sts:SetSourceIdentity to AssumeRolePolicyDocument in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am creating a role using the CDK and I need to add `sts:SetSourceIdentity` to the AssumeRolePolicyDocument.

My code looks like this currently:

```js
new Role(this, 'MyRole', {
    assumedBy: new AccountPrincipal(Stack.of(this).account),
    ...
});
```

This results in an AssumeRolePolicyDocument that looks like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need it to look like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:root"
            },
            "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole", "sts:SetSourceIdentity"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The generate CloudFormation from the CDK code above ends up like this:

```json
  "MyRoleCF2E104D": {
   "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
   "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
     "Statement": [
      {
       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
        "AWS": {
         "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
           "arn:",
           {
            "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
           },
           ":iam::0123456789012:root"
          ]
         ]
        }
       }
      }
     ],
     "Version": "2012-10-17"
    },
    ...
  },
```

I can't figure out how to get the `sts:SetSourceIdentity` added to the `Action` in the CloudFormation. Any ideas? Do I need to eject to the L1 construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addStatements` adds new actions to the role's assume role policy document:

```js
role.assumeRolePolicy?.addStatements(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    actions: ['sts:SetSourceIdentity'],
    principals: [new iam.AccountPrincipal(this.account)],
  })
);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a little weird that I have to add a second statement for this, but it accomplishes what I need.